# What was the "stormy discussion" about differential Galois theory at IHES?

Tags: ho.history-overview, galois-theory, differential-galois-theory

In Kazuo Okamoto and Yousuke Ohyama's paper "Mathematical works of Hiroshi Umemura", *Annales de la faculté des sciences de Toulouse Mathématiques*, XXIX, no. 5 (2020) pp. 1053-1062, there is a reference to a meeting at the IHES in 2010 between Umemura, Pommaret, and Malgrange. This is  described as follows:

> Umemura, Pommaret and Malgrange met at IHES in the fall 2010. Three
> researchers have their own differential Galois theory. After a stormy
> discussion, Umemura and Pommaret did not achieve consensus on
> differential Galois theory. This is the last time that Umemura met
> Pommaret.

What were the issues / differences in approach that led to this "stormy discussion"?